# Button returned from function doesn't work when tapped in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, xcode, foreach, swiftui, return-type

so I have a ForEach loop in my ContentView that calls a makeButton() function a bunch of times. This function returns a button but for some reason the button doesn't do anything when you click on it (AKA, the 'action' doesn't happen). I thought maybe it was something to do with the return type but I'm really not sure what's going on here:

```
ForEach(array, id: \.self) { (client: Client) in
    self.makeButton(client: client)
}
```

and then the function itself looks like:

```
func makeButton(client: SocketClient) -> some View {  
    //calculations for horizontal and vertical offset here
    return Button(action: {
        print("Clicked a button and it should print out \(client.colorVariable)")
    }, label: {
        ZStack {
            Circle()
                .fill(client.colorVariable)
        }.frame(width: 30, height: 30)
        .offset(x: horizontalOffset, y: verticalOffset)
    })
}
```

Comment: What happens if you make the Button its own struct instead of a function? ie `struct ClientButton: View { let client: Client; var body: some View { ... }}`

Comment: @CenkBilgen For simplicity's sake, I removed some of the stuff but essentially the function does a bunch of calculations using variables found within 'client.' The only way I could think of doing that in a custom struct would be in the init but that might be super sloppy--right?

Comment: @CenkBilgen Okay never mind--I just implemented it super quick and even that's not working. in my body I just declared all the constants and did the calculations and stuff and then I returned the button...still not working. Let me know if you want me to post what that looks like.

Comment: Hmm, the other thing is perhaps the hit area of the button. Try the simplest example, just plain Text instead of the ZStack. Then you can adjust the hit area of the button with `.contentShape(...)`, although it looks like you shouldn't need it because you set the frame.

Comment: So I sort of found the issue. I'll update my code up to. I have an offset on the circle and it's causing the button detection point to remain in the center of the screen while the circle moves...any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: You shouldn't have to adjust the offset, maybe another other view in the ZStack is effecting it. In any case `.contentShape` will let you define exactly what the hit shape should be.